# DataGrip connecting to Snowflake getting No Trusted Certificate error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datagrip

Trying to connect to Snowflake using DataGrip and keep getting "No trusted certificate found." error. I've tried downloading the certificate from Chrome and installing it via DataGrip settings section but did not work. I am however able to access my Snowflake account using dbeaver (same jdbc driver). Any ideas?

[image]

and here is the error I get.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the JDBC driver downloaded from Snowflake?

Comment: What is the version of JDBC driver being used in this scenario? Also, was the certificate imported as mentioned here : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/settings-tools-server-certificates.html

Comment: snowflake links to maven. this is where the driver is from. I used 3.9.2 version. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/. Also, added the certificate per jetbrains instructions.

Comment: The latest that Datagrip is loading by default is 3.13.10 and the latest that is available is https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/3.13.22/
Can you try with either of these versions and test?I just tested DG with the 3.13.10 version driver and it worked fine.